# Story length and the term used

Tags: short-story, book-length, novella

At what page number would a short story become a novella and at what point does a novella become a book manuscript? Is there a specific length that the story has to be to achieve to use those terms?

Answer (score 8):

The [Science Fiction and Fantasy Writers of America](http://www.sfwa.org/nebula-awards/rules/) gives these ranges:

- Short story: Fewer than 7500 words.
- Novelette: 7500 to 17499 words.
- Novella: 17500 to 39999 words.
- Novel: 40000 or more words.

Note that these are defined in terms of word count, not page count. The number of pages depends greatly on formatting, so is imprecise as measure of story length.

Comment: Glad I could help. And welcome to the Writers StackExchange. If you like an answer (from me or anyone else), consider upvoting it. And on questions you ask, you can accept the one that best answers your question. Some additional info here: http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: +1, but it's worth noting that the word counts vary wildly from organisation to organisation, the base count for a [Novella](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novella) goes from 7,500 to 20,000 depending on which group you're submitting to, and that's just a small sample.